# Gridsplitter not resizing

Tags: wpf, treeview

I want the GridSplitter to make the TreeView larger to make it easier to see the content of the TreeView. Can not seem to find the right place to put the Splitter

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    <RowDefinition/>
    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    <RowDefinition />
    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

<TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="JSON String" Margin="5"/>
<TextBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>

<GridSplitter Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="2" Height="5"         ResizeDirection="Rows" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>

<TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Text="C# Type" Margin="5"/>
<TreeView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" x:Name="outputTree" Margin="5"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put your `TreeView` into `ViewBox`:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
  <RowDefinition/>
  <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
  <RowDefinition MinHeight="1"/>
  <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
  <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

<ViewBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
  <TreeView  x:Name="outputTree" Margin="5"/>
</ViewBox>
```

[As MSDN says:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox(v=vs.110).aspx)

> ViewBox defines a content decorator that can stretch and scale a
>   single child to fill the available space.

[This WPF tutorial is also helpful.](http://www.wpftutorial.net/ViewBox.html)

The work example:

```
<Window x:Class="TreeViewWpfApplication.MainWindow"
        ...The code omitted for the brevity...
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>     
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="5" />
            <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Viewbox>
            <TreeView Name="treeView">
                <TreeViewItem Header="1">
                    <TreeViewItem Header="1.2">
                        <TreeViewItem Header="1.3"/>
                    </TreeViewItem>
                </TreeViewItem>
                <TreeViewItem Header="2"/>
                <TreeViewItem Header="2"/>
                <TreeViewItem Header="2"/>
                <TreeViewItem Header="2"/>
                <TreeViewItem Header="2"/>
                <TreeViewItem Header="2"/>
            </TreeView>
        </Viewbox>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Height="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
        <Button Grid.Row="2" Content="Hello" Name="btn"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Update:**

I slightly edited your code. Please, see:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>            
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="JSON String" Margin="5"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>

    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="2" 
        Height="5" ResizeDirection="Rows" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    <Grid Grid.Row="3">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock  Text="C# Type" Margin="5"/>
        <Viewbox  Grid.Row="1" >
            <TreeView   x:Name="outputTree" Margin="5">
                <TreeViewItem Header="1">
                    <TreeViewItem Header="1.2">
                        <TreeViewItem Header="1.3"/>
                    </TreeViewItem>
                </TreeViewItem>
                <TreeViewItem Header="2"/>
                <TreeViewItem Header="2"/>
                <TreeViewItem Header="2"/>
                <TreeViewItem Header="2"/>
                <TreeViewItem Header="2"/>
                <TreeViewItem Header="2"/>
            </TreeView>
        </Viewbox>
    </Grid>

    <TextBlock Text="5" Grid.Row="4"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Hello6" Grid.Row="5"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Ok I tried that but by the time I expand the tree it gets so small you can not see it         <Viewbox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
            <TreeView  x:Name="outputTree" Margin="5"/>
        </Viewbox>

Comment: Ok I tried putting the MinHeight and it still does not size right it. The TreeView becomes impossibly small to read when it expands it starts out as an ok size but once it gets longer it is no longer readable

Comment: just looked at your update and discovered a problem with my initial question, I did not include what was in the last 2 rows that you removed         <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Content="Convert" x:Name="btnConvert" Margin="5" Click="btnConvert_Click"/>
        <Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4" Content="Done" x:Name="btnDone" Margin="5" Click="btnDone_Click"/>

Comment: @jsomers89 please, see my **Update** section

Answer (score 3):

Set it to the same row as the second `TextBlock` and set the `ResizeBehavior` to `PreviousAndNext` I tweaked some of your row definitions so adjust as necessary

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition  />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="JSON String" Margin="5"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="5"/>


    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"  Grid.Row="2" Height="5"         ResizeDirection="Rows" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Text="C# Type" Margin="5"/>
    <TreeView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" x:Name="outputTree" Margin="5"/>
</Grid>
```